# Bessel equation of half-order (asymptotic)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, laplace-transform, bessel-functions

Not really optimistic about getting a reply for a question tagged under "Bessel function" but here goes,

I have

$$J_{\frac{1}{2}} = (a_1 \cos(z) + a_2 \sin(z))Z^{-\frac{1}{2}} $$
and
$$Y_{\frac{1}{2}} = (b_1\cos(z) + b_2\sin(z))Z^{-\frac{1}{2}}
$$

$$J_{\frac{1}{2}} \sim \frac{z^{\frac{1}{2}}}{z^{\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{1}{2})!}$$
The asymptotic formula is:

Asymptotic formula:

$$J_m =\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 &m=0 \\ 
 \frac{z^{m}}{z^{m}m!}&, m>0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$Y_m =2 \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{2}{\pi} (\ln(z))&,m=0 \\ 
 \frac{-2^{m}(m-1)!z^{m}}{\pi}&, m>0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

How do I **see** that 
$$J_\frac{1}{2} = (a_{1}(1-\frac{z^{2}}{z!}+ \cdots )+a_{2}(z - \frac{z^{3}}{3!}+\cdots ) )z^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$

This solution came up in a tut sheet I was working up but I'm not seeing how the taylor expansion came about.

Comment: Please don't be so unfaithful, I am quite fond of the creation of the (bessel-functions) tag :)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to notice that the [Bessel differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html)

$$ x^2 y'' + x y'+ \left(x^2-\frac{1}{4}\right) y = 0, $$
for which $y=J_{\frac{1}{2}}$ is a solution, is mapped into a well-known homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients by the substitution $y(x) = \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$.